# Get a number inserted or updated into a table

Tags: mysql

What's the best way to get a number I'm inserting or updating into my database? I'm trying to figure out what count ended up being after this insert:

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO dailies (day, count) VALUES (:day, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count+1');
$pdo->execute(array(':day'=>date('z')));
```

I'm trying to do a fetch, but its not working. I'm guessing because this is an insert or update and not a select.

```
$fetch = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with user variables:

`INSERT INTO dailies (day, count) VALUES (:day, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = (@new_count = count+1)`

Then

`SELECT @new_count`

If the record was inserted, `@new_count` will contain the value you set in the update. Otherwise it will come back as NULL.